# Add data into csv file properly using fputcsv()

Tags: php, regex, excel, csv, fputcsv

I want to add curl data properly into csv file,
When I tried to add data into file data is added all over into csv file ..

I want to add it in only `cell`

Below is my code -

```
<?php

    define('CSV_PATH','csvfiles/');

    $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "file_input_url.csv"; // Name of your input file
    $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');

    $csv_fileoutput = CSV_PATH . "file_output_content.csv"; // Name of output file
    $csvfileoutput = fopen($csv_fileoutput, 'a');

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $csvfileoutput);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");

    $headers = ['URL','Code_content'];

    fputcsv($csvfileoutput, $headers);
    function cleanData(&$str)
              {
                // escape tab characters
                $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);

                // escape new lines
                $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);

                // convert 't' and 'f' to boolean values
                if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
                if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';

                // force certain number/date formats to be imported as strings
                if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
                  $str = "'$str";
                }

                // escape fields that include double quotes
                if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
              }

while($data = fgetcsv($csvfile)) 
    {

        $url = $data[0];
    //  $url = "http://www.partsimple.com/";

        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $str = curl_exec ($ch); 
        curl_close ($ch); 

        cleanData($str);

        fputcsv($csvfileoutput,array($url,$str));

    }

?>
```

### Update

This is the [csv file](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/554444/file_output_content.csv) I am getting with this code. I want all this data in one cell.

like url and into next cell their content.

I tried [this tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/) also to properly format data. But its not working as expect.

Please give some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function cleanData() as follows -

```
function cleanData(&$str)
        {
            //$str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);

            $str = str_replace(array("\n\r", "\n", "\r"), '', $str);

            $str = trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $str));

            $str = preg_replace('/\s+/S', " ", $str);

        }
```